# What is wrong with my question and how can I improve it?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, closed-questions

[This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/146177/which-game-engine-offers-the-ability-to-download-levels), this is about recommendation so it should be closed but here's the thing, downloading parts of the game as the user unlocks level is an important feature that no one talks about. Is it impossible? if so yes then my question is stupid and should be closed, otherwise someone should give an answer, google it for a month and you won't find a tutorial on how it's done.

I asked a similar question of software recommendation.SE and got no answer so I had to come here, I know that it would be closed, but regardless someone has to have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your question is off-topic here is twofold:

First, as it's worded now, you are literally asking us which technology (which engine) to use in the body of the question. This is explicitly considered off-topic here. The title of the question is asking for a list of resources (engines), which is also explicitly off-topic.

The task you appear to be trying to accomplish is extremely broad, and fundamentally *not any different* than downloading any other kind of asset from the internet and doing something with it. There's lots of tutorials available for, for example, connecting to some CDN or web server endpoint via HTTP and bringing down a file.

The other part of your task, loading that level you've downloaded, is also very basic and thus, as specified, very broad. How do you load any of the current levels you have, for example? It should be fundamentally no different provided you've done the first part (downloading the file to the correct location) correctly.

So, the best way to improve your question and make it on-topic is for you to rewrite it to point out that what you're trying to do is implement this feature, and then describe what you have tried already and where you are stuck. Include things like:

- where you are hosting the levels to be downloaded (some CDN like CloudFront? your own FTP server?)
- how do you want to download the levels (HTTP, perhaps)?
- how do you currently load levels from the disk in your game?
- what language and engine are you using?